# How to run a function without getting prompted to continue?

Tags: vimscript

In order to keep my tags file up to date I wrote this function which runs `ctags -R .` whenever I save a file.

```
function! UpdateCtags()
    " assume if a tags file exists - then current dir is ok
    if filereadable("tags")
        echo "updating tags file"
        call system('ctags -R .')
    else
        echo "unable to update tags file - probably wrong current dir"
    endif
endfunction

au BufWritePost * silent! call UpdateCtags()
```

The function seems to work ok, but it triggers a prompts

> ```
> "somefile" 508L, 16090C written  
> updating tags file  
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> ```

Its not a major problem, but considering I save a file probably every 15 seconds, I want a message confirming the function ran to be printed, but I don't want to be interupted by a prompt.
.
Is it possible to make this prompt go away?

Ive tried adding `silent!` to the autocmd

```
au BufWritePost * silent! call UpdateCtags()
```

But it seems to have no effect

Answer (score 4):

After reading this [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts) article, I learnt that the cause of the prompt is content in the command line exceeding the available commandline height

so I added `set cmdheight=2` to the function to this and it now seems to work

```
if filereadable("tags")
    set cmdheight=2
    "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    echo "updating tags file"
    call system('ctags -R .')
    set cmdheight=1
    "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
else
```

Comment: You should probably store the old height and restore it, rather than hard offing the "old" value.